# Is there a way to create a generic function using image crate that creates a white image?

Tags: image, types, rust

I am trying to create a generic function to create a white image in rust.

So far I tried this:

```rust
use imageproc::drawing::draw_filled_rect_mut;
use image::buffer::ConvertBuffer;
use image::{GenericImage, ImageBuffer, Pixel, RgbaImage, Rgba};
use imageproc::rect::Rect;

pub(crate) fn create_square_image<I, P>(source_img: &I, size: u32) -> ImageBuffer<P, Vec<u8>>
where
    I: GenericImage<Pixel = P>,
    I: ConvertBuffer<ImageBuffer<P, Vec<u8>>>,
    P: Pixel<Subpixel = u8>
{
    let (width, height) = source_img.dimensions();

    let mut block_image = create_white_image(size, size);

    let delta_x = (size - width) / 2;
    let delta_y = (size - height) / 2;

    for y in 0..height {
        let target_y = y + delta_y;
        if target_y >= size {
            continue;
        }
        for x in 0..width {
            let target_x = x + delta_x;
            if target_x >= size {
                continue;
            }
            let pixel = source_img.get_pixel(x, y);
            block_image.put_pixel(x, y, pixel)
        }
    }

    block_image
}

pub(crate) fn create_white_image<P>(width: u32, height: u32) -> ImageBuffer<P, Vec<u8>>
where
    P: Pixel<Subpixel = u8> + 'static,
    RgbaImage: ConvertBuffer<ImageBuffer<P, Vec<u8>>>
{
    let mut image = ImageBuffer::new(width, height);
    draw_filled_rect_mut(&mut image, Rect::at(0, 0).of_size(width, height), Rgba([255, 255, 255, 255]));

    image.convert()
}
```

It gives me an error like this while trying to build:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `P: image::color::FromColor<image::color::Rgba<u8>>` is not satisfied
   --> src\util.rs:217:27
    |
217 |     let mut block_image = create_white_image(size, size);
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `image::color::FromColor<image::color::Rgba<u8>>` is not implemented for `P`
```

and I guess I would've been fine if I also made a type constraint on `FromColor`, but it's not made public by the crate for some reason.

Is there something I'm missing?

Active toolchain:

```
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu (default)
rustc 1.43.0 (4fb7144ed 2020-04-20)
```

cargo.toml dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
image = "0.23.4"
imageproc = "0.20.0"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: @Shepmaster thank you for your guidelines! Tried to properly introduce MRE, hopefully it helps.

Comment: The `P` parameter is probably part of the problem. You don't want this to work for any `I` **and** any `P`; you just need it to work for any `I` and then there is only one choice of associated `Pixel` type. For example, add constraints: `I: ConvertBuffer<ImageBuffer<<I as GenericImageView>::Pixel, Vec<u8>>> + GenericImage` and `<I as GenericImageView>::Pixel: Pixel<Subpixel = u8>`. Replace `P` everywhere with `I::Pixel` (possibly with qualification as above).

Comment: Having said that, I couldn't find a working type signature for `create_white_image` without needing `FromColor`. Not that it means it can't be done - I have zero experience with this crate.